# Expressing ranges of piecewise functions where there's a break in its associated $y$-values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For the following piecewise function, how would you express the range? I'm a little confused given the graph breaks between $-1$ and $0$.

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1, & x\ < -5 \\
\sqrt{25-x^2}, &-5 \leqslant x\leqslant 5 \\
x-5,& x > 5
\end{cases}
$$

Would it be correct to express it's range as,

$R:$ $-1 \cup [0,\infty)$

Comment: That's correct, just make sure you add set brackets around the $-1$. So the answer is $\{-1\} \cup [0,\infty)$.